# How to copy the combined value of two column to one Column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table with column id,firstName,lastName,fullName and I want to copy the combined value of column firstName and lastName into fullName column.Is it possible by using query without stored procedure ?

As i know we can set the one column value to other using something like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = column2
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server often require different approaches.  Please can you remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CONCAT function of mysql:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = CONCAT(column2, ' ', column3);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL Server`...

`COMPUTED` column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl
    ADD FullName AS firstName + ' ' + lastName
GO
```

Or permanent `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl
SET FullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat or concat_ws to combine columns.
if you use concat

```
UPDATE table_name SET fullName = concat(firstName, ' ', lastName);
```

and if you use concat_ws

```
UPDATE table_name SET fullName = concat_ws(' ',firstName,lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without UPDATE Just query:

```
SELECT firstName + ' ' + LastName, * 
  FROM table_name;
```

With UPDATE:

```
 UPDATE  Table_Name  
  SET  New_Column = firstName + ' ' + LastName;
```